# Kafka K-SQL Data Types

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have a topic `customer_proposal` and created a stream from it with;

```sql
CREATE STREAM s_customer_proposal (
    produce_time    bigint,
    musteri_no      varchar,
    gds_id          bigint,
    teklif_id       varchar,
    musteri_tip     varchar,
    flow_id         integer
)
WITH (kafka_topic='CUSTOMER_PROPOSAL', value_format='JSON', timestamp='produce_time');
```

when i print the topic i see this;
`print customer_proposal from beginning;`

```
{  
   "ROWTIME":1569679134939,
   "ROWKEY":"null",
   "produce_time":78538331776986478934,
   "musteri_no":100,
   "musteri_tip":"E",
   "flow_id":9,
   "teklif_id":"63918383365017657862",
   "gds_id":78538331776986478934
}
```

but when i query `s_customer_proposal` the `gds_id` is different

```sql
select gds_id from s_customer_proposal limit 1;
```

Result is;

```
4751355482148272470
```

It seems a datatype thing, i tried `int`, `bigint`, and `double` but could not get the actual
value which is `78538331776986478934` in topic;

any idea on this ?

Comment: Do you just have the one message on the topic? I don't think the `SELECT` is deterministic, so if you have multiple messages on the topic it's possible you see them in a different order with `PRINT` with `SELECT`

Comment: I tried it with different combinations, i am sure the numbers are different. topic has only one distinct `gds_id` which is true but stream has different one.

Answer (score 0):

`78538331776986478934` is too large for both the 32bit INT and 64bit BIGINT SQL data types. It would fit in a DOUBLE but only with loss of precision.  If you want to import this number as it is then you'll need to use a `DECIMAL` type.  e.g.

```sql
CREATE STREAM s_customer_proposal (
    produce_time    bigint,
    musteri_no      varchar,
    gds_id          DECIMAL(20,0),
    teklif_id       varchar,
    musteri_tip     varchar,
    flow_id         integer
)
WITH (kafka_topic='CUSTOMER_PROPOSAL', value_format='JSON', timestamp='produce_time');
```

See https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/syntax-reference/#decimal for more info.